# how can I execute a three.js example in my project folder?

Tags: npm, three.js

How can I execute a three.js example in my project folder? The example I want to execute is this:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_keyframes.html
.

After installing three.js through npm, I copied example's source code:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_animation_keyframes.html

in my empty examples folder located at '/node_modules/three/examples'.

I think there's a path direction problem importing some of including library files such as

"import { RoomEnvironment } from './jsm/environments/RoomEnvironment.js';"

"loader.load( 'models/gltf/LittlestTokyo.glb', function ( gltf )"
etc.

Do I have to copy those library files and paste it on the right path by hand? I'm afraid this is not a correct solution. Is there a solution something like, as I wish, downloading all necessary library files in the right places by input some npm command?

Comment: Since you are already working with the `npm` package, I suggest you use a small build tool. Check out the following template for a minimal project setup with rollup. https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm

Comment: try npm and webpack

Answer (score 0):

The situation is certainly not ideal, but here are some tips:

- You can clone the whole repository so you have all the resources used by the examples: `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git`
- You can use a web browser's web page saving feature (Ctrl+S) but be sure to replace the HTML with the example's source HTML, because it will be *much* cleaner. You'll need to fix up file path references, and it may still miss some resources. Also make sure not to get the iframe containing page, but rather the demo itself.
- If Save Webpage As misses some resources, you can use Chrome's dev tools Network tab. Refresh the page to populate it, then right click inside the table > Copy > Copy All as CURL. This will give you a command you can paste in your terminal (in an empty directory, ideally) to download all the resources used by the webpage. This can still miss some resources that are dynamically loaded, such as with 1. the model selector in the LDraw Loader example, in which case you could switch to each model to purposely populate the network requests table, or 2. a fallback for older browsers, in which case you may not be able to get it through this method.
- It's much easier to remove features than to add and combine them, so try to find an example that uses as many of the things you want as possible (without being overwhelmingly complex). It's worth looking outside of the official examples to real projects and third party experiments. Just note that they may not be up to date with the latest APIs.

I hope someone writes a script to automate setting up a Three.js project from an example... and posts a better answer than this!